# Protractor: Is there a way to detect any element that's been clicked?

Tags: protractor

I know how to open a page in Protractor, but want to receive a callback on any element being clicked.  Is there any way to do this?

My guess is that I have to inject javascript and hook up event handler's, but even so how would there be a callback invoked?

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: I'm working on a concept that uses Selenium for DOM discovery and events (clicking, sendkeys) but I want to interact with the user when they click on something randomly.